# fopen access denied no access to php.ini

Tags: php

I've a problem. I have a website from a friend who has created the website on his own server and now trying to set it on my hosting.

The problem now is that I've no permission to the php.ini file so I can't use fopen becease that is not allow on by mine hosting.

is there an alternative?

Martijn

```
$myfile = fopen("../".$enterurl.".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        $txt = file_get_contents("blank.php");
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: What change were you planning on making in the php.ini?

Comment: You mean the function `fopen` is actually denied? If so, an alternative is to find a new host.

Comment: The problem is that ive a 2 year subscription

Comment: Then get in touch with your host and see if there's anything they can do about it. Another alternative in your current case may be to see if `file_put_contents` is also in the function blacklist, if not, then that will do just as well as your current `fopen; fwrite; fclose` code.

Comment: the question is way your host block `fopen`?

Comment: It says no permission

Comment: Saying that you don't have permissions to open a file is not the same as not being able to use fopen. Which one is it? What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: sorry for my late reaction this is a example of one of the error message i get " Permission denied in /home/relax4u/domains/relax4umassage.nl/public_html/php.php on line 14"

Comment: That means the permission to write to php.php is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i had my file permissions not right. So he had no permission to open, change or delete a file. I changed my file permission to 777 or 744